# Help needed on running a MYSQL script in the background of a web page and taking different actions dependent on the result

Tags: ajax, json

I have a form on a web page, with one field to enter a code, to search for a property.

On clicking 'submit' I want to be able to run a script in the background without leaving the page.

The script will need to run a MYSQL statement which will have one of these results:

1. The property code does not exist, so display a Javascript Alert saying it does not exist.
2. The property is for sale, so call an existing javscript function 'saleSubmit(propertyCode)' to overwrite the exsiting web page with a new page sale.php for that property code
3. The property is for rent, so call an existing javscript function 'rentSubmit(propertyCode)' to overwrite the exsiting web page with a new page rent.php for that property code
4. The property is for sale and rent, so display 2 checkboxes within a div on the page to choose either the sales details or the rental details.

Can anybody point me in the right direction here?

---

Hi Nick - I think I screwed the system up a bit as I initially posted a question, then created an account which would not let me comment on the thread.

The status of the query is as simple as: does not exist, sale, rent, sale & rent

Extra advice would be really appreciated as I am problems googling for examples or a tutorial to point me in the right direction.

I first took this approach when I was looking at this problem to check that the form and Select statement were working correctly. So my form code looked like this:

```
<form name="idsearch" action="" method="post" onsubmit="xmlhttpPostForm('includes/idsearch-response.php', 'idsearch', 'idSearchResult', '<img src=\'images/loading.gif\'>'); return false;">
<input type="text" id="idRefNo" name="idRefNo" value="Enter Property Code" onfocus="this.value='';" />
GO <input type="image" src="img/template/search2.gif" alt="Click to Search for Properties"/>
```

and the php code called looked like this:

```
$idRefNo = $_POST['idRefNo'];
```

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM property WHERE property.Title = '".$idRefNo."' AND suspend != 'Yes'"; $result = @mysql_query ($query);
if ($result) { // If the query runs ok
if ($result != "") {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

```
    if ($row["BaseRental"] > 0 AND $row["Saleprice"] > 0) {
        echo 'This property is for RENT and for SALE <br/>';
    } else if ($row["BaseRental"] > 0) {
        echo 'This property is for RENT only <br/>';
    } else if ($row["Saleprice"] > 0) {
        echo 'This property is for SALE only <br/>';
    } else {
        echo 'DOH! What is going on here!!! <br/>';
    }
}
```

As I said above I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction to achieve what I want to do at the beginning of this thread.

Comment: Which language are you using as the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's differentiate between the page(client) and your mysql database(server). Your page will have to send some request to your server which triggers a script to query the database. The result of that query is returned as a response to your page.

You could send a request by using javascript and the [xmlhttprequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) or try [jquery](http://jquery.com/) which offers very simple methods to make requests ([$.ajax(...)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

Your server and the script which queries your db should then return some meaningful status back to your client which has to interprete the result: Doing alerts, showing your div or whatever you'd like to do. I suggest returning the response as json which can be directly used in javascript without any parsing hassle. If the status of your query as simple as: does not exist, sale, rent, sale & rent. You could go as far and encode those as plaintext numbers, no json needed.

Comment: Hi Nick - I have set it up to use

Comment: Nice, if you have any questions about details, go ahead and ask, I'll edit my answer. If this answer is good enough, please accept it.